# Does Android have global error handle function?

Tags: android

In asp.net , I can use the following code to handle error which is not catched.

but android app, I don't know how to write code to avoid whole app crash.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string lr = "\n\n";
    string lan = "";

    try
    {
        if (Request.UserLanguages.Length >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Request.UserLanguages.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                lan = lan + " " + Request.UserLanguages[i];
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    string errorMessage = ex.Message;
    string title = "E: " + ex.Message;

    string LoginedUser = "";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        LoginedUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        LoginedUser = "Anonymous";
    }


    string content = "Error Message: " + ex.Message
                   + lr
                   + "Request URL: " + Request.Url.ToString()
                   + lr
                   + "Request IP: " + Request.UserHostAddress + "    Language: " + lan + "    Logined User: " + LoginedUser
                   + lr;

    content = content + "Beijing Time: " + DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString() + " ( UTC+8 )     Web Server Local Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + lr;


    //-----------------------------------
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    if (Server != null)
    {
        Exception ee;
        const string exceptionFormat = "{0}: \"{1}\"\r\n{2}\r\n\r\n";
        for (ee = Server.GetLastError(); ee != null; ee = ee.InnerException)
        {
            message.AppendFormat(exceptionFormat,
            ee.GetType().Name,
            ee.Message,
            ee.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    content = content + message.ToString();
    //------------------------------------

    if (!Request.IsLocal)
    {
        if (IsCanSend(errorMessage))
        {
            string fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"];
            string toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToErrorEmail"];
            CuiWei.Utility.ATMSendEmail.SendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, title, content, false, "", new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient());
        }
    }

    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx?ErrorInfo=" + ex.Message);
    Server.ClearError();        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code in my onCreate():

```
    final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {        
            //TODO Handle Exception
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    });
```

So you have the possibility to log the error. If you remove the line 
    `"defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);"` 
it should continue runing but the app may be in an undefined state so be careful.

Comment: Perhaps, should invoke in Applications onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

You can implement this as per your need. But I would suggest to take a look at [ACRA](http://acra.ch/). It has much more functionality and it is quite easy to use.